# How to allow copying text when using jQuery UI Selectable plugin?

Tags: jquery-ui

When using [jQuery UI Selectable](http://jqueryui.com/selectable/) it is impossible to select and copy text from elements to which Selectable plugin is attached.
Example is at [jQuery UI Selectable homepage](http://jqueryui.com/selectable/): you cannot select and copy texts "Item 1", "Item 2" and others.

My question is how to allow standard select-copy in this case?

As a workaround I tried to find a way to temporary disable this plugin to allow user select and copy text. But plugin's [`disable()`](http://api.jqueryui.com/selectable/#method-disable) method does not work for this scenario - it just disables plugin's select feature but still not allows to select-copy text.
So help here is appreciated too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is ok for you to temporary disable selectable plugin, then use select-copy and then to turn selectable on, then you can use destroy method

```
$(".selector").selectable("destroy");
```

and after that recreate selectable

```
$(".selector").selectable();
```